# How to polar align an equatorial mounted telescope when you are close to the equator?

Tags: amateur-observing, telescope

I recently moved to southern Mexico (16 degrees N) and I wonder what would be the best way to align my EQ telescope when the polar star is not visible?

Comment: Polaris should be 16° above the northern horizon.

Comment: I know...I forgot to mention an important factor: I'm surrounded by mountains that block my northern view for like 20°.

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out where due north is and aim about 4° below the top of the mountains. If I knew a good way to do that I'd post an answer, but a compass, a level, and a protractor might help. (Polaris is about 1° off the celestial north pole anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount a camera on the tripod and take a long exposure. You should be able to determine the concentric circles of the stars paths. The center of the circle is the North pole.